# Enforce validation on a TexBox when text changes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, mvvm

I'm using `Validation` on TextBox as follows

```
<TextBox BorderThickness="1" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxInError}"
Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationTemplate}">
     <TextBox.Text>
         <Binding Path="TimeBeforeDeletingPicture" Mode="TwoWay">
              <Binding.ValidationRules>
                   <helpers:TimeBeforeDeletingRule/>
              </Binding.ValidationRules>
         </Binding>
     </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

The validation fires when I leave the TextBox (apparently when it looses focus), I want to validate the input every time the text changes, I'm using `MVVM` so I don't want to mess with events, what's the correct clean way to achieve that.

Comment: Have you tried with `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set UpdateSourcetrigger as follows

```
 <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="TimeBeforeDeletingPicture" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
```