# WPF: Validate TextBox content immediately

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, textbox

Is there a way in WPF/XAML to indicate that validation should be performed immediately (after each character is entered in a `TextBox`) instead of when the focus is lost?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556383/enforce-validation-on-a-texbox-when-text-changes-in-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should detect the event "keyup" or "keydown" and check if the input is correct.

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    if (e.Key == YourKey)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```